# Matplotlib double major tick labels?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a datetime x-axis vs. a simple count on the y-axis and a second line which is a rolling average.

I am experiencing an unexpected double x-tick label at the major points which looks as follows.

[image: double axis major tick labels]

code is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24,15,dpi=144)
x = df["Date"].values.astype('datetime64[M]')

ax.plot(x, df["Count"],'--',label='Count')
ax.plot(x, df["Moving Average"], label = 'Moving Average')

yloc = matplotlib.dates.YearLocator()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(yloc)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))

ax.legend()
ax.grid(axis='y')
ax.grid(axis='x',which='major')

ax.minorticks_on()

plt.show()
```

I'm not sure why I am getting the double labels on the major xticklabels, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set both minor and major ticks on years. If you only want to have grids on major ticks you can remove major labels by changing the major formatter:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter(''))
```

Otherwise, you have to use different tickers for minor and major.